# Unity | How to load an apk file in script?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, unityscript

I want to load the apk file in unity.

For example, loading apk file to put package name is possible in android. However how can I implement this function in unity script?

If it isn't possible to load the apk file in Unity, how can i kill the apk(unity project) file in the script? I mean, the game would be terminated if press the button.

This is the code in android below.

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.sampelgame");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Does anyone have an idea? How can't i do this in unity.

Comment: Did you try to use android plugins? http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html

Comment: @Dalmas Yes i know but unfortunately i can't use this in some reason... so I just decided to use "Application.quit()" because the apk which calls my unity apk file isn't terminated. It just load my game apk. Thanks anyway :-)